# How to "Iterate" on Computer Vision machine learning model?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision-api

I've created a model using google clouds vision api. I spent countless hours labeling data, and trained a model. At the end of almost 20 hours of "training" the model, it's still hit and miss.

How can I iterate on this model? I don't want to lose the "learning" it's done so far.. It works about 3/5 times.

My best guess is that I should loop over the objects again, find where it's wrong, and label accordingly. But I'm not sure of the best method for that. Should I be labeling all images where it "misses" as TEST data images? Are there best practices or resources I can read on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert, but here's what I'd suggest in order of most to least important:

1) Add more data if possible. More data is always a good thing, and helps develop robustness with your network's predictions.

2) [Add dropout layers to prevent over-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879504/how-to-apply-drop-out-in-tensorflow-to-improve-the-accuracy-of-neural-network)

3) Have a tinker with [kernel and bias initialisers](https://becominghuman.ai/priming-neural-networks-with-an-appropriate-initializer-7b163990ead)

4) [The most relevant answer to your question] Save the training weights of your model and reload them into a new model prior to training.

5) Change up the type of model architecture you're using. Then, have a tinker with epoch numbers, validation splits, loss evaluation formulas, etc.

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT: More information about number 4**

So you can save and load your model weights during or after the model has trained. [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) for some more in-depth information about saving.

Broadly, let's cover the basics. I'm assuming you're going through keras but the same applies for tf:

### **Saving the model after training**

Simply call:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("{Your_Model}.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("{Your_Model}.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

### **Loading the model**

You can load the model structure from json like so:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json 

json_file = open('{Your_Model.json}', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

And load the weights if you want to:

```
model.load_weights('{Your_Weights}.h5', by_name=True)
```

Then compile the model and you're ready to retrain/predict. `by_name` for me was essential to re-load the weights back into the same model architecture; leaving this out may cause an error.

### **Checkpointing the model during training**

```
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath={checkpoint_path},
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

# Train the model with the new callback
model.fit(train_images, 
          train_labels,  
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(test_images,test_labels),
          callbacks=[cp_callback])  # Pass callback to training
```

Comment: I'm specifically curious about how to do 4

Comment: Sure, there you go! Edited my answer.

Comment: @thisguy123 Just note: loading the weights of a previous model is sort of like a bootstrap, but you don't want to over-train the network. Keep an eye on your loss/accuracy metrics. I found that changing my validation metric + kernel bias init values helped too me a fair bit.